# What type/thickness of drywall should be used in water heater closet?

Tags: drywall, water-heater

I have a rental house built in the 70's that had severe water damage in the small room (4x5 feet) that houses the hot water heater. The room is off of the garage. I've had the water heater replaced and removed the dry wall. I'm getting ready to replace the drywall, but I'm concerned about what is the proper product to put back on my walls. Is 1/2 inch drywall adequate or should I put heavier dry wall back up?

Comment: Fun fact - here in California, we sometimes put the water heater OUTSIDE - often in a little shed built onto the outside garage wall.  They even make prefab little metal sheds for this purpose.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Modern codes generally require 5/8" fire-rated drywall (Type X) between a garage and the living areas of a house.  Double check with your local city/county/state as they may have more stringent requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Check your local codes and consider talking with your insurer. Our local codes were less stringent than what our insurance company suggested. We went with the insurance company's recommendation.